# Java Android Client Socket not working

Tags: java, android, sockets

Am I missing something.  I've checked other posts and have thses set in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Whenever I try to create a new socket on Samsung Galaxy Express it never gets past this line.

```
Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4736);
```

This is my class for starting a socket in a runnable.

```
private class SendThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4736);       <---never gets past this
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())), true);
            out.println(sendString);
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            Log.d(TAG, "sent");
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "end");
    }

}
```

Server Socket

```
private class ReceiveThread implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket receiverSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private Socket socket = null;

    public void run() {
        try {
            receiverSocket = new ServerSocket(receivePort);
            receiverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            while (killConnection == false) {
                Log.d(TAG, "listening");
                socket = receiverSocket.accept();
                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
                Log.d(TAG, "Input from server" + input.toString());
                String s = input.readLine();
                //UpdateUi(s);
                socket.close();
            }
            receiverSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ok yes the server-side socket isn't listening

Comment: Is there somebody listenig on IP `10.0.0.2` and port `4736`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it never gets past this line"? does it throw an exception? If so, what's the exception?

Comment: @Marc It doesn't even throw an exception that's whats bugging me.  This is connected to a click even and I'm just clicking the button trying to send a simple string right now.  I can click over and over and it just stops at the same place every time no exception fires.

Comment: @Tichodroma ok if I sit there for a couple minutes I finally see the socket timeout so server-side isn't listening thanks Tichodroma

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is a unique alias for the loopback interface of a deveopment machine hosting an android **emulator**.  That feature **does not exist on actual devices**.  You will have to use an actual network address on wifi, or via (ab)use of tethering in order to reach a local server.

Comment: Socket timeout doesn't mean the server isn't listening at the port. It means it didn't respond. Possibly it was unreachable.